# How to make all text smaller on page (using apex 5 and the universal theme)

Tags: css, oracle-apex

I am using apex 5 and the universal theme.

I have an application which looks better when the browser is zoomed to 75%.   (The default text size is pretty large and most pages have at least two regions where one updates based on selections in the other.  It just fits on screen much better when it's all a bit smaller)

Consequently I'd like the page to always look like this or as close to this as possible.  Is there a simple way to use CSS have make all the text 75% of the current size?

Comment: Hi, do you use a reset.css file? You can use percentages or em. CSS3 has some new values for sizing things relative to the current viewport size.

Comment: No.  I was rather hoping to add css to the theme roller used in the universal theme in apex 5.